# How to group duplicated rows and count them?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, count

my table:

```
id | item_id
1  | 5
2  | 5
3  | 7
4  | 2
```

sql:

```
$countWeek = $conn->query("SELECT count(item_id) FROM `myTable` GROUP BY `item_id`")->fetchColumn();
```

As you can see i have 2 duplicated rows with `item_id = 5` i want to group these duplicated rows and output `3` rows on the count, but when i do `echo $countWeek` it output `1`, why?

When i change the above sql to:

```
$countWeek = $conn->query("SELECT item_id FROM `myTable` GROUP BY `item_id`")->rowCount();
```

It returns the correct value, but i don't want to use `rowCount()` because i only need to count the rows and `fetchColumn()` with `count()` is far better in terms of speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use counct(distinct item_id)

```
    SELECT count(distinct item_id) 
    FROM `myTable`
```